How to fix stairs where tread nosings are breaking off
These tread nosings are breaking off, which makes them a serious trip and fall hazard. I could put the nosings back on but I'm leaning toward that being a bad idea considering it's inevitable that this will happen to another one.  I'm by no means a handyman/carpenter but do ok with tools and can probably call in my nephew (who is a handyman) to help as well. What would be the best way to fix these stairs?




Your question is rather vague, and what you should do is somewhat subjective. You need to decide whether you want to reattach these parts, replace the covering, or replace the treads altogether. All three are viable. Once you've done that we can help with more specific questions.

The stair tread covers appear to be (not so well) glued-together pieces of solid wood. These pieces are overlaid on the old stair treads and don't insert under the side trim to be locked in.
The pieces are breaking at the glue joints, so the tread covers were poorly glued. Proper wood gluing would rip apart the wood rather than break at the glue joint.
You could replace these failing tread covers with single-piece (not multi-piece glued-together) stair tread plates. Rip the old ones off and apply the new ones. Being solid one-piece treads, they won't break at the tip like these are doing.

Definitely gets me in the right direction. Thanks!
